# Get query(search handler) configuration for a query using SolrJ

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

Is it possible to get the query configuration values(default + request parameters) using SolrJ ?

For example: If I direct a request to the RequestHandler using SolrJ, I would like to get a list of parameters(default + overridden request parameters) used on the query. I need this to log the current configuration when the query was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the parameter `echoParams=all`.

> The echoParams parameter tells Solr what kinds of Request parameters
>   should be included in the response for debugging purposes, legal
>   values include:
>
> - none - don't include any request parameters for debugging
> - explicit -
>     include the parameters explicitly specified by the client in the
>     request
> - all - include all parameters involved in this request, either
>     specified explicitly by the client, or implicit because of the request
>     handler configuration.

Take a look at [Common Query Parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-TheechoParamsParameter)